# How to center an image in an amp-carousel?

Tags: amp-html, google-amp

Have an `amp-carousel` with several `amp-img`

See it here:
https://codepen.io/jaygray/pen/bLXwax

Each `amp-img` is displayed in a `slide`.

The `amp-img` is an SVG.

Each `amp-img` is viewable in an `amp-lightbox` (click the image).

The carousel and the lightbox work as expected.

But i cannot center the `amp-img` in the `slide`.

How to center the `amp-img` in the `amp-carousel` `slide`?

Comment: please share your code

Comment: are you looking for a subset of the code on codepen?

Comment: yes share the codepen

Comment: see the link on line 2 of the question: https://codepen.io/jaygray/pen/bLXwax

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `<amp-img layout='fixed'>` to `<amp-img layout='fill'>`

Add CSS `.slide > .inner-image-wrap > amp-img > img{ object-fit: contain;   }`

[Working Url](https://codepen.io/bachchasingh/pen/KQOBxZ)